# Reached CPU time limit in R

Tags: r, mixed-models

I was running `anova` of two `lme` objects (linear mixed effect model in the `nlme` R package), and loop over ~15,000 times (comparisons). However, I encountered an error which says:

```
Error in pdConstruct.pdMat(object, value, form, nam, data) : 
  reached CPU time limit
```

What does this tell me? Is it because of the computational capacity of my computer, or it is inherent in the algorithm in R? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at the source code for `pdConstruct` , as it may have a call to `setTimeLimit` . Take a look at the help page for the latter to see how you might change the limit.